# Separate tables for logging?

Tags: database-design, table, logging

I would like to log new products, updates to products and deletions of products (and the same for other schemata [customers, locations etc]).

Would it be best to have a separate table (e.g. ProductLog, CustomerLog) for this, so that I can have a product foreign key as a field in the ProductLog, customer foreign key in the Customer Log etc?

Or should I use one table to avoid creating essentially double the amount of tables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to store historical configuration settings for each row of data without cramming all the configuration settings into each row of data?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/284803/is-it-possible-to-store-historical-configuration-settings-for-each-row-of-data-w)

Answer (score 0):

When using MSSQL you can use temporal tables to track versions of your record.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables

Answer (score 0):

Yes I would use separate tables.

I worked in a company where we were doing the same for the exact same reason.